# Include hard-coded value in INSERT..SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure in SQL which works fine. But I want to insert a text 'POSTED' into `Assesable` column while executing the procedure; I need help to achieve this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBankToAll]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AllPayandRec (BID, EntryDate, Typez, FullName, Assesable)
        SELECT 
            Bank.BID, Bank.EntryDate, Bank.Type, Bank.Assesable  
        FROM 
            Bank                       
        LEFT JOIN 
            AllPayandRec ON Bank.BID = AllPayandRec.BID 
        WHERE 
            AllPayandRec.BID IS NULL
END
```

Thus insert 'POSTED' into all rows as part of executing the procedure

Comment: Did you miss part of the query? This shouldn't work because your `SELECT` columns don't match up to your `INSERT` columns (ie you are inserting 5 cols but only selecting 4).  Other than that, just replace `Bank.Assesable` with `'POSTED'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO AllPayandRec (BID, EntryDate, Typez, FullName, Assesable) 
SELECT Bank.BID, 
       Bank.EntryDate, 
       Bank.Type, 
       Bank.FullName, 
       'POSTED' 
FROM Bank LEFT JOIN AllPayandRec ON Bank.BID = AllPayandRec.BID 
WHERE AllPayandRec.BID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. sorry for the late reply. it worked

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly, I think I got grudge downvoted.  :o)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBankToAll]
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO AllPayandRec           
      (BID
      ,EntryDate
      ,Typez
      ,FullName
      ,Assesable)
SELECT Bank.BID
      ,Bank.EntryDate
      ,Bank.Type
      ,Bank.FullName
      ,'POSTED'  
FROM Bank                      
 Left JOIN AllPayandRec ON Bank.BID = AllPayandRec.BID 
WHERE AllPayandRec.BID IS Null
END
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but code without any kind of explanation is only half of an answer.

Comment: @PeterB Agreed, but to be fair, this change didn't really require a lot of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace it with `"POSTED"`in `SELECT` statement :

```
INSERT INTO AllPayandRec (BID, EntryDate, Typez, FullName, Assesable)
     SELECT Bank.BID, Bank.EntryDate, Bank.Type, Bank.FullName, 'POSTED'
     FROM Bank LEFT JOIN 
          AllPayandRec 
          ON Bank.BID = AllPayandRec.BID 
     WHERE AllPayandRec.BID IS NULL;
```